# Converting jpeg to bmp version 4 using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I can't seem to find a way to properly convert my images to bmp using imagemagick. Whenever I use this website with the current settings it works flawlessly in my program. https://online-converting.com/image/convert2bmp/

I've tried these commands:

```
convert disney.jpeg -format bmp:format=bmp4 out.bmp
convert disney.jpeg -define bmp:format=bmp4 -type truecolor -compress none out.bmp
```

Nothing seems to work. Not sure how to set up imagemagick so that it gives me back the same format as the website.

As for the program, you basically feed it the bmp file. It works when I convert with the website, but not with imagemagick.

Comment: The default is BMP4. So `convert disney.jpeg out.bmp`

Comment: That's what I read but the article and comments were written a few years ago and there's now BMP5, so I assumed that was the default. Either way, I tried running the code and it doesn't work. There is something that online-convertering.com is doing to the file that I guess is different. It looks like they set it to true color, so I tried doing -type truecolor and it still doesn't work on imagemagick. I need to find a way to take a users uploaded image and convert it on the backend, and well the website doesn't seem to have an API or anything I can call with my program or else I would use that.

Comment: I'm going to look into the rows direction, see how I can set it to bottom-top on imagemagick. Maybe thats it?

Comment: add `-intent undefined` as in `convert disney.jpeg -intent undefined out.bmp`

Comment: If you are using `convert` you probably have an old version of **ImageMagick**. Try updating to v7 and try `magick disney.jpg BMP4:result.bmp`